# Java Overriding: Can I override variables in class?

Tags: java

Our professor wants us to modify the codes she provided while keeping it intact. I guess what I can do to keep the code intact while adding modifications is by using Inheritance and Polymorphism.

public class ShapesApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form ShapesApp
 */

Shape [] shapes = new Shape[]
{
    new Circle(new Point(50,60), new Point(130,180)),
    new Rectangle(new Point(50,200), new Point(150,350)),
    new Circle(new Point(200,300), new Point(350,350)),
    new Rectangle(new Point(100,100), new Point(250,250)),
    new Circle(new Point(150,150), new Point(300,300)),        
};
    
Color [] colors = new Color[] {Color.cyan, Color.green, Color.red, Color.blue, Color.magenta, Color.orange};
```

//More codes but not related to the query.

I'm wondering if what should I do to override the codes above.

Comment: You can override methods not variables

Comment: Hi!! Thanks for the help!! but the code did not work, however, we got a clarification that we can change this .java file that our professor provided, therefore, I do not need to override it :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class that extends this class and @Override the methods you wish to change.

For variables, since you're extending the class you should be able explicitly just re-declare them. (Unless they're private).

Comment: I actually tried that but the codes above is not inside a method and we cannot change the codes she provided.

Comment: You should be able to do as I suggested. Which part didn't work ? Please add what you've tried in your question.

Comment: I created a class that extends ShapeApp and tried to override the codes inside it. However, after running the program, everything still follows the code inside

Comment: I tried this and the program still creates the code above instead of just one circle.

Comment: Shape [] shapes = new Shape[]
    {
        new Circle(new Point(50,60), new Point(130,180))      
    };

Answer (score 0):

In your child class, simply give the variables different values in an instance initializer block.

```
public class YourClass extends ShapesApp {
    {
        shapes = new Shape[]{
            //...
        };
        colors = new Color[]{
            //...
       }
    }
}
```